# Dynamic Flat File Connection to import new file everyday

Tags: ssis

I have to create a job which imports data from .csv file into database table everyday. I have created the job and it works fine as long as the filename is same.

The file that comes in everyday has a different name, so i am trying to set up dynamic flat file connection. As i have only one file to load everyday i am not trying to use For Each Loop Container and also, i am not good at script task.

I was trying to see if there is any other way to achieve this using SSIS.

I have created a variable for my path "C:\Daily Files\" as @[User::MyFilePath]. I am then using this variable in the ConnectionString Expression property of the Flat File Connection Manager.

But it does not work. I get an error saying the Cannot open the datafile.

Can someone tell me what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a connection manager to a file that changes name everyday, you will have to write some kind of expression to do so. On the other hand, the easier way out is to use the For Each Loop container as it does not care what the name of the file is as long as you give it *.csv in the qualifying field.